# how Google or Facebook keep me login in different web sites

Tags: authentication, oauth, authorization, integrated

How in different google services like Gmail, youtube pages connected to my account
and integrated them.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here you find all the details about Google's login system:
https://developers.google.com/accounts/docs/OAuth2Login

> Google APIs use OAuth 2.0 for both authentication and authorization.
>   This document describes Google's underlying OAuth 2.0 implementation
>   for authentication, which aligns with the OpenID Connect
>   specification.

and

> Note: If you provide a “sign-in with Google” feature, we recommend
>   using Google+ Sign-In. Google+ Sign-In is built on the OAuth 2.0 and
>   OpenID Connect protocols. It supports over-the-air installs, social
>   features, and a sign-in widget on top of standardized OpenID Connect
>   sign-in flows. Google+ Sign-In works for all users with a Google
>   account, whether or not they have upgraded to Google+.

Answer (score 0):

Margaret Rouse says in "[single-sign-on](http://searchsecurity.techtarget.com/definition/single-sign-on)":

Single sign-on (SSO) is a session and user authentication service that permits a user to use one set of login credentials (e.g., name and password) to access multiple applications. The service authenticates the end user for all the applications the user has been given rights to and eliminates further prompts when the user switches applications during the same session. On the back end, SSO is helpful for logging user activities as well as monitoring user accounts.